# Check if custom uri is valid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, uri

So i'm opening a standalone Unity app from a UWP store app. In my UWP app I use the unity WSA class to launch the custom uri I created. 
Example:
In the register I created a custom uri called test:
In UWP app c# I use:

```
string uri = @"test:";

    // Launch the URI
    Launcher.LaunchUri(uri, true);
```

This works fine. The app launches. However if the app does not exist it pops up a dialogue to ask me with what I want to open it. Can I check this also while launching? So if the user has the app not installed I give the user feedback? I tried pretty much every class available for Unity and uri's etc. None of them do what I need. I had high hopes for a few, but all they did was tell me if the URI i entered are valid uri formats, rather then checking if it can actually open the app.

EDIT: Also, what's the difference between Launcher.launchURI and Application.OpenURL?

Comment: the popup only appears if there are multiple aplications registered for a given uri

Comment: Appearently it doesn't? I'm a 100% sure I only have 1 app linked to the custom uri. I made the uri myself in the regedit and linked it to a path. On that path is only app.EDIT: To add to this, what i meant was when I use a different uri link in c# it gives me te popup to select a app. What I want, instead of giving me a popup I want it to give me feedback the original uri scheme couldn't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Application.OpenURL opens a url in the default browser, while Launcher.LaunchUri starts the default app associated with the specified URI.

And no, from the UWP app you just can’t query the system whether the URI is registered or not, there is no such API.

And LaunchUri just returns false if no app is launched, but at that time an error dialog is already prompted, so checking the return value of LaunchUri is not a solution either.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I do notice Application.OpenURLworks for standalone as well, while Launcher.LaunchUri only works for UWP. The app we're trying to open is our own desktop app. Does that mean it doesn't matter which one we use? Since both of them open our app just fine. Second, I see. So LaunchUri already returns false. Is there no way to catch this off/check this? I just want it to skip or at least check if the windows popup asking for a app to open it with is launched. Maybe there's another way of opening a app from UWP and catching this? Any information is welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have no experience with Application.OpenURL, so I don’t know if you can use it in the UWP app. But if you want to do what you want from within a UWP app -  checking register and launch the standalone Unity app if some uri is registered - then your best bet would be FullTrustProcessLauncher. One of UWP’s design principles is it lives inside a sandbox, it has very limited knowledge about other apps on the same device - it can launch a URI but it has no idea if the URI is registered.

Comment: And with the fullTrustProcessLauncher you CAN check that? Or you can still only launch it? Asking this so i'm not wasting time trying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using it in my project so I know this can be done. The idea is not checking with FullTrustProcessLauncher, but checking by using another app, FullTrustProcessLauncher is used to launch that app. The UWP app and the app communicate with each other thru [app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). It takes some effort to learn and implement all these but it should work.